# How to redirect in the events.addUserLoaded Angular 6

Tags: angular, oidc-client-js

I'm using the oidc-client library. After the Login, in the call back I call signinRedirectCallback(), but the User is not immediately loaded and I cannot redirect to the Protected page until is loaded. I tried to add router.navigateByUrl('/protected'); in the events.addUserLoaded but when it runs,  it returns an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigateByUrl' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by user is not loaded, 
signinRedirectCallback() returns a promise, this will return you a promise.

if you do like below, you will get user object immediately.

```
yourOidcManager.userManager.signinRedirectCallback().then(user => {

});
```

Look at this 
https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/blob/dev/src/UserManager.js#L98